# how to display global dictionary items in table view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dictionary

There are two views in my project: in the first one users input two words and those words are saved in a dictionary as the key and the value. The code in short:

```
var words = [Dictionary<String, String>]()//<-declared outside the class
words.append([input.text: input2.text] as! [String : String])
```

Then in the second view, I want to display all the saved words in table cell like so:
[image: table view]

And I have found some code for doing that, but it works only for a local dict:

```
class TableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


// Data model: These strings will be the data for the table view cells
let animals: [String] = ["Horse", "Cow", "Camel", "Sheep", "Goat"]

// cell reuse id (cells that scroll out of view can be reused)
let cellReuseIdentifier = "cell"

// don't forget to hook this up from the storyboard
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Register the table view cell class and its reuse id
    self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)

    // (optional) include this line if you want to remove the extra empty cell divider lines
    // self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

    // This view controller itself will provide the delegate methods and row data for the table view.
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}

// number of rows in table view
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  return self.animals.count
}

// create a cell for each table view row
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // create a new cell if needed or reuse an old one
    let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as UITableViewCell!

    // set the text from the data model
   cell.textLabel?.text = self.animals[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

// method to run when table view cell is tapped
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("You tapped cell number \(indexPath.row).")
}
}
```

I have edited the code above like so:

```
var wordIndex1 = words.count - 1

class TableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var word = words[wordIndex1] as? Dictionary<String, String>

    let cellReuseIdentifier = "cell"

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return (self.word?.count)!
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as UITableViewCell!

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.word?.keys.first

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("You tapped cell number \(indexPath.row).")
    }
}
```

But it only displays the last added value whereas in the first code it creates a new cell for each new value.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: you have an array of dictionaries , each dictionary contains 1 key/value , so this `var word = words[wordIndex1] as? Dictionary<String, String>` has count  = 1

Comment: ohh I finally get it now.. then how can I display all of them? Maybe create an array for the dict keys and another array for the dict values?

Comment: you really need to follow `struct` way but see edit below

Comment: Use swift tuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access array index = number of items you need

```
var wordIndex1 = words.count - 1
```

or in short

```
if let lastWord =  words.last {
  ////
}
```

note array indexing starts with 0 and to numberOfElemnts - 1

---

Also it's better to have a model

```
struct Item {
  let leftInp.rightInp:String
}
```

then create the array like

```
var arr = [Item]()
```

---

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return words.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier) as UITableViewCell!

    let dic = words[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = dic.keys.first

    return cell
}
```